# Required Parameter is not present em projeto Spring MVC com spring Boot utilizando Thymeleaf

Tags: mvc, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estou gerando um formulário no código html do meu projeto e utilizando o Thymeleaf para criá-lo. Alguns campos do formulário são do tipo input pois o usuário precisa inseri-lo, outros são do tipo select pois já existem aqueles dados no banco e o usuário deve selecionar um. O código compila mas apresenta erro de que parâmetros não estão presentes, entretanto não consigo visualizar o trecho de erro.

Estou me baseando na documentação:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Parte do código html(somente o select):

```
<div>
                    <label for = "professor">Professor</label>
                    <select name = "professor">
                        <option th:each = "professor : ${professor}"
                            th:value = "${professor.prof}"
                            th:selected = "${professor.prof == selecionado.prof}"
                            th:text ="${professor.prof}">
                    </select>   
            </div>

            <div>
                    <label for = "disciplina">Disciplina</label>
                    <select name = "disciplina">
                        <option th:each = "disciplina : ${disc}"
                            th:value = "${disc.id_disciplina}"
                            th:selected = "${disc.id_disciplina}"
                            th:text ="${disc.id_disciplina}">
                    </select>   
            </div>
```

Trecho do código que está mapeado para o path em questão:

```
@GetMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView cadastraTurma(@RequestParam ("professor") Long prof, @RequestParam ("disciplina") String id_disciplina){
        ModelAndView turmasCadastro = new ModelAndView("/turmasCadastro");
        Professor professor = new Professor();
        professor = profDao.getOne(prof);
        Disciplina disc = new Disciplina();
        disc = discDao.getOne(id_disciplina);
        turmasCadastro.addObject("professor", professor);
        turmasCadastro.addObject("selecionado", new Professor());
        turmasCadastro.addObject("disc", disc);
        return turmasCadastro;
    }
```

Comment: Olá Juliana, poderia mostrar a mensagem de erro, talvez facilitaria para entender o problema?

Comment: Obrigada! Para resolver o problema eu mudei o parâmetro do método cadastraTurma para sem parâmetros e o método que está associado a ele que realiza o POST tem como parâmetro o objeto Professor a anotação @ModelAttribute